# Practice ATM Use Case Diagram

Tags: architecture, diagram, use-case

I'm currently a Software Developer and I would like to become a Software Architect in the future. As practice, I've decided to create a use case diagram for a factitious ATM. I've learned about use case diagrams in the past and I'm hoping that you guys can take a look at my diagram and give me some tips and/or constructive feedback.

- Are there any errors in the diagram?
- Is the diagram too detailed / not detailed enough?
- How can I improve this diagram?
- Any books that you recommend for someone who is striving to become an Software Architect?

Here is a link to my diagram:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction include insert card and enter pin number and if that user is authorized than only it can select task.
i hope this will help you..
and for ATM use sequence diagram rather than UML diagram

Comment: Use this link to create Sequence diagram for ATM  https://www.google.co.in/search?q=sequence+diagram+of+atm+machine&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=Hnh9UPrNNcPlrAf4v4CoDA&sqi=2&ved=0CCMQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=921

Comment: if this answer suits you don't forget to vote up for this.. hehe:-) @steven